# How to get deleted item name from SharePoint using CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to extract deleted List item metadata at least name from SharePoint list using CSOM and C#.
My code is

```
 ChangeQuery cq = new ChangeQuery(false, false);
        cq.Item = true;
        cq.Folder = true;
        cq.File = true;

        cq.List = true;           
        cq.DeleteObject = true;           
        client.Load(list);
        client.ExecuteQuery();
        ChangeCollection coll = list.GetChanges(cq);
        client.Load(coll);
        client.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (ChangeItem itm in coll)
        {
            var s = itm.ChangeType;
            ListItem item = list.GetItemById(itm.ItemId);
            client.Load(item);
            try
            {
                client.ExecuteQuery();// got error
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

I have already define List and clientcontext object.

Thanks
Shyams

Comment: What error are you getting?  What is the values of your itm properties when you get the error?

Comment: I am getting delete item id.But when   ListItem item = list.GetItemById(itm.ItemId);
            client.Load(item); do this and execute , it gives error , item is not exists .

Comment: I think you should search for getting items from recycle bin using csom and get it from there if possible.

Comment: yes, i am also thinking same thing.